# Show/Hide span based on an item inside the span

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I have the following in a form.  It gets cloned and I want to be able to turn the display on of just one item.  My cloning increments the number in the Name and ID of the input item.

```html
<span style="display: none;">
  <input type="checkbox" id="regsenior_1" name="regsenior_1" class="test-checkbox" value="Senior"/>
  <label class="test-checkbox-label">Senior</label>
</span>
```

When other changes are made to the form I run a javascript function.  Inside that function I want to turn on the display of the the input item and the label.  I can get the input item by its ID. and this will show that, but not the label:

```
document.getElementById(regSeniorID).style.display = "inline-block";
```

How can I step up to the span and change the display to show everything inside the span?

Note that `regSeniorID` = `regsenior_` + the clone number to grab the correct unique item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you tagged jQuery you can do this:

```
 $('#' + regSeniorID).parent().parent().find('span').hide();
```

this will find the right span element and will eventually show it.

Comment: I have tried `$(regSeniorId).parent().find('span').show();` and also `$('#' + regSeniorId).parent().find('span').show();` and neither are working, but giving no error in the console.  I am logging regSeniorId to the console so I know the line is being hit and the variable is set correctly.  But the items are not being shown (or hidden if I flip things to always show the item and try to hide it via the code)

Comment: I had to go up one more parent.  I edited the answer to show this.